# C# inheritance, access attribute value from child class

Tags: sql, inheritance

I have a category class with a name and a description attributes :

```
public class Category
{
    public Category(){}
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
 }
```

And i have child class that has category as parent but with an extra attribute which is the ccolor.

```
public partial class Car : Category
{
    public Car()
    {
    }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

Now i need to access the color attribute from a sql query :

```
   public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategory(string categoryName)
        {
            return db.Database.SqlQuery<Category>("SELECT * FROM " + categoryName).ToList();
        }
```

The output result has only the name and description value, but how i can access the color which is specific to the car or an table sent in param (dont worry i have my code avoiding the SQL injection :) )? knowing that i already have a color value in my car table.

or there's a way to cast a dynamic Object  :

```
Object DynamicObject = "Car" // passed in params;                                         SqlQuery<DynamicObject>("SELECT * FROM " + categoryName);
```

That will solve my problem

Thank you.

Comment: why are you doing `SqlQuery<Category>("car")` instead of `SqlQuery<Car>` ?

Comment: Why public <string> ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the SQL layer you're using? This may help answer the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your query:

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<Car>("SELECT * FROM CAR").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're querying the `CAR` table, your output is being deserialized into `Category` objects. Since `Category` does *not* have a `color` field, the field is not created.

The issue is also one of polymorphism - your query layer doesn't know to return `Car` objects even though the table you've queried could match a `Car` and `Car` is a valid return for objects of type `Category` - you asked it for `Category` and that's what it created.

Comment: All you answers make sens and i know my mistake now, but there's way to put a to cast dynamic object ? see my original post, i did changes. Thanks

Comment: a `dyanmic` object won't help here, since the runtime still sees `Category`